# Анимация на css 3

Tags: css, css3

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать бесконечную анимацию на css 3

```
<div class="animate">
   <img src="..." class="img-1">
   <img src="..." class="img-2">
</div>
```

Нужно, что бы картинки плавно исчезали и появлялись, что бы первая картина быстрее появлялась и исчезала, чем вторая.

Без js.

Comment: `animation`, `@keyframes`, про это всё есть в многочисленных статьях и учебниках, с чем конкретно возникли затруднения?

Answer (score 4):

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  animation: blink 5s linear infinite;
}

img + img {
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% { opacity: 1 }
   50% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/b472aba2616317f1f438273c05e3bb6d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
```